# CRC16-CCITT Calculation

Tags: ios, swift, crc16

I was trying to create a CRC16-CCITT calculation in swift. But the values are not expected. I want to find out which one is wrong, my code or values of specification document. Can someone help me with this.

According to Spec,(CRC16-CCITT)
initial value : 0xFFFF
Input : 0xAA
Calculation Direction : MSB First (Left Shift)
Output : 0x0AAF

Here is the code

```
func crc16ccitt(data: [UInt8],seed: UInt16 = 0x1d0f, final: UInt16 = 0xffff)->UInt16{
    var crc = final
    data.forEach { (byte) in
        crc ^= UInt16(byte) << 8
        (0..<8).forEach({ _ in
            if (crc & UInt16(0x8000)) != 0 {
                crc = (crc << 1) ^ 0x1021
            }
            else {
                crc = crc << 1
            }
        })
    }
    return UInt16(crc)
}
```

**UPDATED Answer**

```
func crc16ccitt(data: [UInt8],seed: UInt16 = 0x1d0f, final: UInt16 = 0xffff) -> UInt16{
    var crc = final
    data.forEach { (byte) in
        crc ^= UInt16(byte) << 8
        (0..<8).forEach({ _ in
            if (crc & UInt16(0x8000)) != 0 {
                crc = (crc << 1) ^ 0x1021
            }
            else {
                crc = crc << 1
            }
            //crc = (crc & UInt16(0x8000)) != 0 ? (crc << 1) ^ 0x1021 : crc << 1
        })
    }
    return UInt16(crc ^ final)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The initialization of CRC should be

```
var crc = final
```

and the update of the CRC should be

```
    crc ^= UInt16(byte) << 8
```

With those changes, your code produces the checksum `0xF550` for the input `0xAA`. Note that `0xF550` is expected `0x0AAF` with the bit order reversed, so that is the missing step in your calculation.

Using the methods from [crc-16 cccitt problem - incorrect calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54679243/crc-16-cccitt-problem-incorrect-calculation/54679666#54679666) that would be

```
func crc16ccitt_false() -> UInt16 {
    return crc16(data_order: straight_8, remainder_order: reverse_16, remainder: 0xffff, polynomial: 0x1021)
}
```

Example:

```
let tData = Data([0xAA])
print(String(format: "crc16ccitt_false:  %04X", tData.crc16ccitt_false())) // 0AAF
```